# Implement SHA512 hash in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, sha512

I need to hash string in angular 2+ with SHA512, but i couldn't find any library or function to do that. Do you know of any solution to that?

Comment: You can use this package with angular.

* https://www.npmjs.com/package/sha256

Comment: @PardeepJain: `SHA256 != SHA512`.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, i found the solution. I installed this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha512)

then I included this package into my service (you can include it in component or wherever you need it) like that

```
import * as sha512 from 'js-sha512';
```

and finally used it as it says in documentation like that:

```
sha512.sha512('Message to hash');
```

The library has to be used to get to the function provided by it.

Comment: Note you can use it with: `import { sha512 } from 'js-sha512';`
And then, create your hash like this: `sha512.create().update(<something_to_hash>).hex()`